# ng-clip in datatables using server-side processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, zeroclipboard

I have AngularJS frontend app with PHP backend. Also I use ng-clip ( zeroclipboard ) and datatables with server-side processing. All rows are returned from server side and one output of row looks like this:

```
"aaData": [
    {
        "id": 287,
        "email": "random@email.com",
        "displayName": "Name Surname",
        "role": "Some Role",
        "school": "Some school",
        "section": "Some section,
        "token": "<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\" type=\"button\" clip-copy=\"'https://somesite.com/register?token=DPXpGssPzQYrkiH6Oktw9mvtw5BzWLAb '\"><i class=\"fa fa-copy\"></i></button>",
        "datetime": "06.10.2014 20:51",
        "actions": "<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\" type=\"button\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i></button>\n                                <button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-default\" type=\"button\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i></button>"
    },
```

And because that datatatables gets output ng-clip plugin isn't working. I don't know why it's not working but looks like datatable rows are loaded after ng-clip, that is loaded on pageload, so

Question is how can I re-init ng-clip so each row's button would work, or how can I could make workaround for this ?

```
"token": "<button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\" type=\"button\" clip-copy=\"'https://somesite.com/register?token=DPXpGssPzQYrkiH6Oktw9mvtw5BzWLAb '\"><i class=\"fa fa-copy\"></i></button>"
```

Button should copy contents of `clip-copy=""` which differs in each row.

<kbd>[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wV2da1wfbqC7gfPuuzVv?p=preview)</kbd>

This demonstrates that first button does copy, and copy buttons in datatable rows aren't working

Comment: can you just give me a jsfiddle

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/wV2da1wfbqC7gfPuuzVv?p=preview As you can see, copy buttons in table rows aren't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, because you load the data after angular, it will not compile the `clip-copy` directive. To force this behavior, you can recompile your table element on each `redraw` of your table.

Basically, use the `fnDrawCallback` option provide by *Datatables*, and `$compile`.

```
.withOption('fnDrawCallback', function(table) {
  $compile(angular.element(table.nTable).contents())($scope);
})
```

Here is your updated <kbd>[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0TarL5bzI388nsjRTDHv?p=preview)</kbd>

As a side note, you don't have to explicitly write anything in your *HTML* like you did with the `<thead>`, it's automatically generated. You should also take a look at [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to prevent you to use the redundant *array-based syntax*.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for answer, but I didn't understood about "redundant array-based syntax". Can you explain more about it ?

Comment: With `ngAnnotate`, you can inject your dependencies the default way and it will not break in your minification process. More info [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/deep-dive-in-angular-dependency-injection.html) and on the [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) repository

Comment: Thanks, I'm using yeoman and it has ng-annotate, but I'm new to angular, and saw that way in examples, so it means that ng-annotate will automatically add dependencies before minification ?

Comment: No, you've already set your dependencies. It will allow you to write your injections in multiple ways (as seens on their readme) and don't bother with minification since it will handle the annotations for you